# Flex 4 Programatically Add Item to <s:List>

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, list, actionscript

How can I add an item to a Flex 4 `<s:List>` component that has an item renderer? Here is the code sample of the list that I would like to append data onto:

```
<s:List contentBackgroundAlpha="0" borderVisible="false" id="reviews"
            itemRenderer="renderers.ReviewRenderer" dataProvider="{data}"
            top="10" minHeight="1">
  <s:layout>
    <s:VerticalLayout useVirtualLayout="false" requestedMinRowCount="1" gap="35"/>
  </s:layout>
</s:List>
```

The `data` variable that the `<s:List>` is bound to will have the exact same properties as the object that I would like to append on the list.

Please let me know if I can provide any more details.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I add an item to a Flex 4  component that has an item
>   renderer?

You wouldn't.  You would add an item to the List's dataProvider.  Then the list decides how to display the elements in the dataProvider based on other factors, such as the layout and the itemRenderer.  For visual purposes, one way to view the list is as a collection of itemRenderers.  There is one itemRenderer for each displayed item in the list.

In most cases there will be fewer items displayed in the list than there are items in the dataProvider. itemRenderers are re-used as the list is scrolled through, and the data property on the itemRenderer instance is modified.

So, if you want to know how to add an item to a List's dataProvider, it depends on the dataProvider type.  Assuming an ArrayCollection, you should do something like this:

```
this.data.addItem(myNewItem);
```

Comment: After I posted my question, I realized that I need to update the `dataProvider`. Thank you, and let me check into that...

Comment: Yep, that's it. ;) This is like the 5000th Flex related question of mine that you have answered. Thank you for your time.

Comment: In most cases, adding an item to the data bound by dataProvider should do the trick, because List control would "observe" the data list.  This, however, requires the data list dispatch change event when items are added/removed from the list.  In your case, if you the data list is an `ArrayCollection`, you should be safe.